# Discolouration at the top of dragon's tail

Tags: health, bearded-dragon

It started a few days ago. At first, I thought he was shedding but now I see it’s nothing to do with that. What is it?

There are no reptiles vets around here. I've had dragons many times and never seen this.

He’s 3 years old and was very active and healthy until now. Today he doesn’t want to eat.

[image]

Comment: i do not know anything about reptiles but it do look like some type of fungal inffection so you need to go to a vet to get this treated.